# How to call Google API using CORS in Dynamics CRM

Tags: cors, cross-domain, dynamics-crm

I have a simple call out to google API from a javascript webresource in Dynamics CRM 365.

```
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={' + searchString + '}&types=address&language=en&crossDomain=true&key=[ourKey]', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

//do something with the response here

        };
        xhr.send();
```

I get the following messages and errors in dev tools in IE:

*SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={55 lllll}&types=address&language=en&crossDomain=true&key=[ourKey] required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
File: ClientApiWrapper.aspx

SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={55 lllll}&types=address&language=en&crossDomain=true&key=[ourKey] required CORS preflight.
File: ClientApiWrapper.aspx

SEC7120: Origin http://[ourURL] not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
File: ClientApiWrapper.aspx

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
File: ClientApiWrapper.aspx*

Looking through CORS related material and guides, I believe I've done everything right.

I've also tried this, albeit I expect a CORS issue here:
  jQuery.post('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={' + searchString + '}&types=address&language=' + langCode + '&key=[ourKey]', function (addresses) {
                try {

```
//Do something with returned addresses here...

            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("AutoComplete ErrorInt: " + e.message);
            }
        });
```

I'm sure this is a Dynamics CRM related issue where dynamics doesn't play nicely outside it's own sandbox.

Can anyone please suggest a fix within the Dynamics CRM realm?

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you need to configure your Dynamics CRM to send its `Origin: http://[ourURL]` header along with the request. If not configurable, you can try setting it yourself: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Origin', 'http://[ourURL]');`.

Comment: Yep, tried that. Both the full URL and just the wildcard... still nada.
I'm sure CRM suppresses the headers going out, even if they're set.
Funny, raised a ticket with MS Support, they say it is a google issue. But thi sworks outside of CRM so, no.
ANY other suggestions? ANYONE?

Comment: After adding the header with full URL, I get this: SEC7120: Origin http://[ourUrl] not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
File: ClientApiWrapper.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` headers are **response** headers, which are sent from the server in response to your request.

Just remove them completely from your xhr request code. The browser will add the `Origin` header for you (you do not specify it explicitly), and the server at `maps.googleapis.com` *should* add the required CORS response headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and possibly some others).

If you're still getting problems after that, post a full set of request and response headers for the GET request (and for the preflight OPTIONS request if there is one).

**EDITED FOLLOWING COMMENTS**

OK, so here's what I see from your comments (formatted):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/…{' + 
searchString + '}&types=address&language=en&crossDomain=true&key=[ourKey]', 
true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    //do something with the response
};
xhr.send();

Errors: SEC7120: Origin http://[ourUrl] not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. File: ClientApiWrapper.aspx

GET /maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={55%20saddl}&types=address&language=en&crossDomain=true&key=[ourKey] HTTP/1.1
Accept: / 
Referer: http://[ourURL]/[ourOrg]/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=1166920881
Accept-Language: en-CA
Origin: http://[ourURL]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: maps.googleapis.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 16:26:36 GMT
Expires: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 16:31:36 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

OK, so the browser **is** sending the Origin header. That means that your server needs to return some CORS response headers.

So you need to add code at the **server** to return the following CORS response header for OPTIONS, GET and POST requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value of Origin request header>
```

(what I mean by that is that the server should extract the value of the Origin request header (i.e. `http://[ourURL]`) and return that as the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header. Don't hardcode it as '`http://[ourURL]`' - that way lies madness!).

You will *also* need to return the following additional CORS headers for OPTIONS requests only:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: <value-of-Access-Control-Request-Method request header>
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: <value-of-Access-Control-Request-Headers request header>
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

That last one specifies the number of seconds that the browser should cache the preflight OPTIONS response, so it doesn't need to get made each time. It is optional, but advised. 86400 seconds = 1 day.

That should get you going.

Comment: here's the script, the error and request/response headers from dev tools (F12) 
javascript:

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={' + searchString + '}&types=address&language=en&crossDomain=true&key=[ourKey]', true);
            xhr.onload = function () {
                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  //do something with the response
            };
            xhr.send();

Comment: And here's the error...
Errors:

SEC7120: Origin http://[ourUrl] not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
File: ClientApiWrapper.aspx

Comment: Request Headers:

Request: GET /maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={55%20saddl}&types=address&language=en&crossDomain=true&key=[ourKey] HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://[ourURL]/[ourOrg]/form/ClientApiWrapper.aspx?ver=1166920881
Accept-Language: en-CA
Origin: http://[ourURL]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: maps.googleapis.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

Comment: Response Headers:

Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 16:26:36 GMT
Expires: Wed, 25 Apr 2018 16:31:36 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Comment: Rory, I have no control over the google server. I followed the CORS advice page on google here:https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors AND a few posts on stack and elsewhere, hence my query including the crossDomain=true param. So I'm guessing the google API I'm calling to is not CORS compatible...? OR is there anything I can do in script (like set preflight options) to enable this or get the google server to send back appropriate headers?

Comment: OK, just try sending the request to the server without passing any additional headers (basically just the `xhr.open`, with no additional parameters specified. That might not require CORS anyway.

Comment: So I input this right into a browser: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input={55 sadd}&types=address&language=en&key=[ourKey] and that returns json from google as expected, however, I'm calling this from a script from a Dynamics CRM form thus I'd expect all needs to comply with CORS. BTW, I appreciate the help you're giving me, it has forced me to re-look at everything in the script. Still no luck though. I THINK that CRM really restricts through the clientapiwrapper.aspx. If I enable cross-domain-data-access in the browser, it all works but we can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

So, after all that messing around, I posted an issue on Google API dev support. Here's what came back...hope it helps other's trying something similar:

*Thank you for posting.
I can see that you are using Places API Web Service in your HTTP request. Places API web service is not intended to be used on client-side applications as responses don’t contain the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. See more in the duplicate issue.
To use Places API in a JS application, I suggest you use the Places Library in Maps Javascript API [1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places.). This library offers an autocomplete[2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) feature that you can find in Places API web service.  If you want the queryautocomplete feature of the web service, Javascript API provides getQueryPredictions() function as stated in the documentation [3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService).*